# It is possible by using automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a set of nested classes from datasource (VSO) and I would like to mapped to contracts. The point of mapping is the next:

- the mapped object (contract) will have a new property, called AreaPathFull, which will have the concatenated AreaPath values of all nodes above it in the tree.

**Why I want this?**:

- it is for displaying purposes on UI
- it can be solved on UI side by dealing with javascript is pain in the bottom for me, C# much easier, might not be the best idea ever, but still...

**Question**:

- it is possible to achieve this by using Automapper?

Unfortunately, I have almost nothing experience with Automapper and if it is not possible then I would not like to spend my time with it. If so, then I think, [CustomValueResolve](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers) will be my friend.

**Source**:

```cs
public class Class1ToBeMapped
    {
        public string AreaPath = "Level1";

        public List<Class1ToBeMapped> Children = new List<Class1ToBeMapped>()
        {
            {new Class1ToBeMapped()
            {
                AreaPath = "Level21",
                Children = new List<Class1ToBeMapped>(){}
            }},
            {new Class1ToBeMapped()
            {
                AreaPath = "Level22",
                Children = new List<Class1ToBeMapped>(){}
            }}
        };
    }
```

**Mapped object**, desired result:

```cs
public class Class2Mapped
    {
        public string AreaPath = "Level1";

        public string AreaPathFull = "Level1";

        public List<Class2Mapped> Children = new List<Class2Mapped>()
        {
            {
                new Class2Mapped()
                {
                    AreaPath = "Level21",
                    AreaPathFull = "Level1/Level21",
                    Children = new List<Class2Mapped>()
                    {
                        {
                            new Class2Mapped()
                            {
                                AreaPath = "Level31",
                                AreaPathFull = "Level1/Level21/Level31",
                                Children = new List<Class2Mapped>()
                                {
                                    {
                                        new Class2Mapped()
                                        {
                                            AreaPath = "Level41",
                                            AreaPathFull = "Level1/Level21/Level31/Level41",
                                            Children = null
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            new Class2Mapped()
                            {
                                AreaPath = "Level22",
                                AreaPathFull = "Level1/Level22",
                                Children = new List<Class2Mapped>()
                                    {
                                        new Class2Mapped()
                                        {
                                            AreaPath = "Level32",
                                            AreaPathFull = "Level1/Level22/Level32",
                                            Children = null
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },

            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: I think a [custom type converter](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters) would be better, as that gives you complete control over the mapping.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it!